# Getting Failed to authenticate error on smtp when trying to send mail using swiftmailer with office 365 oauth2 accesstoken

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, swiftmailer

I am trying to send mails using swiftmailer and office 365 which failed to authenticate. I have purchased an office 365 account, azure subscription. My environment is php.
Steps I did:

1. Created office 365 account
2. Created an app in Azure AD
3. created client secret
4. Set Authentication as "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any
   Azure AD directory - Multitenant)"
5. set API Permissions
6. Downloaded Microsoft Graph sdk to generate accessToken
7. I generated accesstoken and used the it on swiftmailer transport as
   password and setting the auth type as "XOAUTH2"

Here is the list of screenshots supporting above activity.

[Athentication settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hymr.png)

[API Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3CFN.png)

I used below sample code from "https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php" to get accesstoken.

```
    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/v2.0/token';
$token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$accessToken = $token->access_token;
```

Below is the complete code

```
require_once 'swift/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'graph/vendor/autoload.php';




$tenant_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
//$graphMailer = new graphMailer($tenant_id, $client_id, $secret_id);

$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenant_id . '/oauth2/v2.0/token';
$token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$accessToken = $token->access_token;


// echo $accessToken;




$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.office365.com', 587, 'tls'))
    ->setAuthMode('XOAUTH2')
   ->setUsername('sender@Testmail699.onmicrosoft.com')
    ->setPassword($accessToken)
;

$transport->start();

$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
  ->setFrom(['sender@Testmail699.onmicrosoft.com' => 'Anish V M'])
  ->setTo(['toaddresss@gmail.com', 'toaddresss@gmail.com' => 'Anish'])
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);

echo $result;
```

I am wondering if any one can point me in right direction. Or tell me if I miss something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disabling one setting on my WHM root login solved the **failed to authenticate error on smtp** for me:

WHM **>** Home **>** Server Configuration **>** Tweak Settings **>**
Restrict outgoing SMTP to root, exim, and mailman (FKA SMTP Tweak) [?]

Comment: This was not the cause of issue in my case. I tried another code from https://github.com/CoasterKaty/PHPGraphMailer/tree/main  and found it is working. But I already have Gmail SMTP setup with Oauth and swiftmailer, it takes "->setAuthMode('XOAUTH2')" and accesstoken from google. So I am trying to use the same authmode for Microsoft. But when I try normal mode with username and password, it works with Microsoft SMTP authentication.